# error: invalid method declaration; return type required for android

Tags: android

I have some trouble these codes. I want to send message between the bluetooth devices. But sendReceiver function have some error. Erorline is actually is that:

```
public sendReceive (BluetoothSocket socket){
        bluetoothSocket=socket;
        InputStream tempIn =null;
        OutputStream tempOut=null;

        try {
            tempIn=bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
            tempOut=bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


    }
```

My problem is :
error: invalid method declaration; return type required

I look all of the same question. But there is no any answer.

And the all of functions about sendreceive.

```
 private class  SendReceive extends Thread{


    private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
    private final InputStream inputStream;
    private final OutputStream outputStream;




    public sendReceive (BluetoothSocket socket){
        bluetoothSocket=socket;
        InputStream tempIn =null;
        OutputStream tempOut=null;

        try {
            tempIn=bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
            tempOut=bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


    }


    public void run(){
        byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
        int bytes;
        while(true){
            try {
                bytes=inputStream.read(buffer);
                handler.obtainMessage(STATE_MESSAGE_RECEIVER,bytes,-1,buffer).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

    }

    public void write(byte[] bytes){
        try {
            outputStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor name is in-correct. Instead of `sendReceive` use `SendReceive`.

Since you have declared `InputStream inputStream` &`OutputStream outputStream` as `final`, either initialize them in your constructor or remove `final`. If you don't need them at class level, then simply remove them and use it at method level.

Comment: if i use this way. I have this error: "error: variable inputStream might not have been initialized"

Comment: Thank you very much. I remove the final and it is working now.

Comment: @DuyguDemirpence No problem. Remember to mark it as accepted, so that others can benefit too